# Error in pom.xml, maven issue

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, maven-2, pom.xml

Few days back my maven project was running fine. Out of nowhere I started getting this weird error.

> org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiver.getManifest(org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject, org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiveConfiguration)

I am attaching image also to show how it actually shows this error.[image: actual error in pom file]

My pom file looks like this...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>SS</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.rolta.dss</groupId>
        <version>5.2.0.16</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>AndroidImpl</artifactId>

    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>AndroidImpl</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <platform.version></platform.version>
        <android.plugin.version>3.8.2</android.plugin.version>
        <jdk.version>6</jdk.version>
        <jdk>${env.JAVA_HOME}</jdk>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rolta.dss</groupId>
            <artifactId>Core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rolta.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-support</artifactId>
            <version>v13</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${env.BUILD_NAME}</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.9.0-rc.2</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>19</platform>
                    </sdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <executable>${jdk}/bin/javac</executable>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jvm>${jdk}/bin/java</jvm>
                    <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have tried removing .m2 folder, checked if any of the dependency was missing in .m2 folder(everything is present). When i do maven clean and maven install i get build success message. I have also checked jdk version(it's 1.6).Even i tried in new eclipse still the issue persists.

Is there anything else which i am missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using a new version (3.0.0) of maven-jar-plugin somewhere in your pom file...This is only related to m2e...(Ticket is already done and a fixed does also exist...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is related with the m2e-plugin in eclipse. You can verify by running
maven from commandline (which you already did), which should give no error.

It's because of UTF-8 formatted (BOM at the beginning) pom.

https://github.com/tesla/m2eclipse-mavenarchiver/issues/6

You could try with the latest: https://otto.takari.io/content/sites/m2e.extras/m2eclipse-mavenarchiver/0.17.0/N/LATEST/

Comment: The issue is https://github.com/tesla/m2eclipse-mavenarchiver/issues/8 which is related to that.

Comment: True this issue is related to m2e plugin. I solved it though. Thanks for the reply guys.

Answer (score 1):

While searching the cause of the issue i stumbled on this link [eclipse issue with the pom](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=360087#c3)

So I checked my current version of the m2e plugin and the sonatype version it was something

**m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.0.20130601-0317 org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group**  and

**0.17.0.201502101659 org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.feature.feature.group Sonatype, Inc.** respectively.

I checked current version this way **(Help > about eclipse > installation details)**

Then i uninstalled those two plugins and issue was resolved.

To uninstall **(Help > about eclipse > installation details > select the plugin > uninstall)**

I uninstalled them because i wanted to upgrade the m2e to the latest version i.e 1.6 [update m2e link](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases)

I was unable to upgrade due to someother reason so i tried uninstalling the previous version and thought of updating the latest one. But once I uninstalled the previous version issue was resolved.